# Executor framework abnormal behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

Hi I am using Executors for loading some data in parallel. My application is fetching some data from DB which have parent-child relation like:

```
parent 1 -> [child11, child12,..., child1N]
parent 2 -> [child21, childy22,..., child2N]
.....
parent N -> [childN1, childyN2,..., childNN]
```

Now here I want parallel processing. What I am doing now is loading all data
of a parent child set at a time from DB and calling executor service to map those in relationship and store in my data structure.

Now the code I have for this:

**The Parent Child relation is like:**

```
public class Post implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer postId;
    private String  postText;
    private String  postType;
    private Integer menuItemId;
    private boolean parentPost;
    private Integer parentPostId;
    // Contains all the Child of this Post
    private List<Post> answers = new ArrayList<Post>();
    ....
    //getters and setters
}
```

**Now I have a wrapper for this Post class for synchronization**

```
public class PostList {

    private List<Post> postList;

    public PostList() {
        super();
        this.postList = new ArrayList<Post>();
    }

    public List<Post> getPostList() {
        return postList;
    }

    public synchronized boolean add(Post post) {
        return postList.add(post);
    }

    public synchronized boolean addAnswer(Post answer) {
        for(Post post : postList)
        {
            if(post.getPostId() == answer.getParentPostId())
            {
                post.getAnswers().add(answer);
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Now My Loading code from DB is:**

```
/* This is called to load each parent-child set at a time, when the 
first set is fetched from DB then call to executor to store those in  
internal data structure. */

List<Post> posts = null;
PostList postList = null;
Integer args[] ={menuItemId};
// Fetch all Posts which are in parent child relation
posts = getDataFromDB(...)
if(posts != null && posts.size() >0)
{
    postList = new PostList();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for(Post post : posts)
    {
         executor.execute(new PostProcessor(post, postList));
    }
    logger.debug("Starting executor shutdown...");
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            logger.error("Interrupted executor >>", ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
    logger.debug("All post loading done ...");
    logger.debug("PostList >> " + postList);
    if(postList.getPostList() != null)
        return postList.getPostList();
}
```

**And in PostProcessor I have**

```
public class PostProcessor implements Runnable {

    private Post post;
    private PostList postList;


    public PostProcessor(Post post, PostList postList) {
        super();
        this.post = post;
        this.postList = postList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Post answer = null;
        try
        {
            // if Post is parent / is a question
            if ("Q".equalsIgnoreCase(post.getPostType())) 
            {
                // do some operation
                postList.add(post);
            }
            // Post is an Answer, so add the answer to proper Question
            else {
                answer = post;
                postList.addAnswer(answer);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Throwable throwable)
        {
            logger.error(throwable.getMessage(),throwable);
        }
    }
}
```

But it behaving abnormally, some time its loading all question post but not all answers and some times its not loading a parent post at all. Please help where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why not use an ORM like Hibernate?

Comment: Multi-threading implies no ordering guarantees. But your code relies on an ordering, it silently fails to add an answer if the question hasn’t been loaded yet.

Comment: Thanks and Yes. That approach must be helpful. But then I need to integrate hibernate. But at present i am looking for the mistakes I have done with this code.

Comment: @Hogler. But i have an order by in my db query by the post id which is an auto incremented key. And the fact is any post of type question will be added in db before any of its child. Thus will appear before its child in the list. And list maintains order of iteratio

Comment: You are using an `ExecutorService` with ten threads. This will *not* retain any order. Point.

Comment: By the way, it’s not clear why you are using a thread pool anyway. All your jobs are doing is adding items to `ArrayList`s within `synchronized` code blocks. There is no benefit from multi-threading here and it seems you didn’t understand the implications of using multi-threading, so the best solution is simply not to use it.

Comment: Thanks @Hogler. Sorry that I am not able to state my problem. But if u take a better look at the code , u can see there is a do some operation comment before adding the post in the arraylist. That part I ommit for simplicity. Where i can get the benifit of multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `addAnswer` fails then it should return false or throw an exception; this indicates that the appropriate question has not yet been loaded or doesn't exist.  Two options:

1. Process all questions first, and throw an exception if an answer doesn't match a question.
2. When you query the database, get a count of questions and decrement this every time a question is processed (do the decrement **after** you add the question to the post list, otherwise you might wind up with a `question_count == 0` but without a question having been added to the list yet); if an answer fails to match up to a question and `question_count > 0` then put the answer back on the queue, else throw an exception.

---

More as a matter of efficiency than correctness, I suggest that you eliminate the `synchronized` methods and use thread-safe data structures from [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) instead - this will reduce lock contention.  This would look something like

```
public class PostList {

    private AtomicInteger questionCount;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Post> questions;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Post>> answers;

    public boolean addQuestion(Post post) {
        questions.offer(post);
        if(answers.putIfAbsent(post.getPostId(), new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>()) 
             != null) {
            questionCount.decrementAndGet();
            return true;
        } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate question id");
    }

    public boolean addAnswer(Post answer) {
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Post> queue = answers.get(answer.getParentPostId());
        if(queue != null) {
          queue.offer(answer);
          return true;
        } else if(questionCount.get() > 0) {
          return false;
        } else {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("answer has no question");
        }
    }
}
```